CHOOSECOLS function in Google Sheets: how to add to select and group query
Creating a SELECT and GROUP query in Google Sheets results in a duplicate 'group' column (Col Q) at the end of my Gviz URL. I want to edit the query so that this duplicate column (4th column) does not appear in my Gviz URL output.  I don't know where to introduce the CHOOSECOLS function in the query function, if that is how to do this?  This is my query:
select Q, Y, J, max(Q) where Y is not null and not Y like '[%' group by Q, Y, J
Where do I put the CHOOSECOLS function in the above query?  And will this work to create the Gviz URL?

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

The recent edit added GViz, which makes this a different question. If you cannot aggregate and re-order the data in the source spreadsheet, you will have to drop columns at the receiving end. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead. See How do I ask a good question?


choosecols() would enclose your whole query from the outside & not to be used within the query. If your query output is lets say 4 columns and you wish to disregard the last column(4th one), then just use:
=choosecols(query(..,"select Q, Y, J, max(Q) where Y is not null and not Y like '[%' group by Q, Y, J"),1,2,3)


I created this query:
choosecols(query(..,"select Q, Y, J, max(Q) where Y is not null and not Y like '[%' group by Q, Y, J"),1,2,3)
When I put the "=" at the start I get a 'Formula parse error'.
The URL is concatenating these rows in the Google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EVqYNprXrR0AofYJ_4583dTw8WClWRItl8Z_L9VwQ2c
/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&gid=
&tq=
choosecols%28query%28..%2C%22select%20Q%2C%20Y%2C%20J%2C%20max%28Q%29%20where%20Y%20is%20not%20null%20and%20not%20Y%20like%20%27%5B%25%27%20group%20by%20Q%2C%20Y%2C%20J%22%29%2C1%2C2%2C3%29

I think I see I have to add my data 'range' in where .., is.  I still get a Formula parse error. Sorry, I've never done this before in Google Sheets.

The suggested choosecols formula is meant to work within the google sheet cells & dont think they are supported to create Gviz URLs. I'd suggest to edit your question to highlight the gviz thing bcoz that's a separate concept altogether

Thanks, that's answered it.  Thank you again for all your help, I feel like I'm learning a great deal.  I'll edit my question as you suggest.  Thank you again.

Isnt it super easier to just save the query output in a separate new tab & then use that tab gid value(instead of default 0) & columns A,B,C in your gviz URL?!

One way to do that is to merge the columns with hstack() and then get unique combinations with unique(), like this:
=unique(hstack(Q1:Q, Y1:Y, J1:J))

To add the two select conditions, use this:
=query( 
  unique(hstack(Q1:Q, Y1:Y, J1:J)), 
  "where Col2 is not null and not Col2 starts with '[' ", 
  0 
)

